# How were the related products added to the site?

Tags: magento-1.7, related-products, cross-sells, up-sells

I am freelancer with a little knowledge of magento. The client gave me the task to determine how were the related products, up-sells and cross-sells added to the site. Can you help me with it?

There are cron_jobs from cron_schedule, which were active last day: advd_notification_job, advr_geo_update, asyncindex, avatax_processqueue, campaigner_integration, campaigner_integration_background_tasks, campaigner_integration_latest_orders, campaigner_integration_orders, campaigner_integration_products, captcha_delete_expired_images, captcha_delete_old_attempts, core_clean_cache, officetrax_information, mirasvit_helpdesk, mirasvit_helpdesk2, mstcore_logger_cron, newsletter_send_all, scheduler_run_operations, spr_update_active, strattas_core_logger_cron, warp_flushcat, warp_flushcms, warp_flushprod, xmlconnect_notification_send_all.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i0xl.jpg
I think that creation time and update time of products are close. So it may be import. How can I determine which peace of code add up-sells?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say. 
Either they added them themselves to products (inside a product admin page, you'll see the relevant tabs on the left side), or there is a cronjob importing products from somewhere.

You can verify whether or not `cron.php` is inside your server's crontab, if it is, then crons are added to the table `cron_schedule`.

You can also look at when the given products were added to the site. In the table `catalog_product_entity` you'll find the creation date. If the dates are really close (say about a second apart), then it is surely done via an import of some sort.

Without further information, it is not possible to help you.

Comment: I added the information to the post. Can you help me?